# MRTK 2.0.0 - WMR Controller Model and Shader not included?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, windows-mixed-reality, mrtk

The newer versions of MRTK-vNext (v2.0.0 Beta 2), don't seem to contain the ability to load the native Controller meshes & shaders. Is there anyway to get these implemented like older versions, or is this something that will be added in the -near- future? The MixedRealityConfigurationGuide states:

> The MRTK does not currently support native SDK's controller models as Unity does not yet provide the capability to load / render gLTF models, which is the default type of models provided by most SDKs. This will be enhanced when this is available.

However, previous versions of the HoloToolKit seemed to have this implemented? I can understand why controllers for Oculus and OpenVR haven't been implemented yet, but why not the WMR ones. Is there anyway to add the older methods into a project running V2.0.0 Beta 2?

Answer (score 1):

There is an initial pull request out to address this issue:
https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/pull/3548

This functionality took longer to port based on HTK's gltf importing logic using a newtonsoft library for json serialization. Newtonsoft version conflicts paired with Unity's il2cpp compiling was generating issues for different MRTK community members. Luckily, another community member provided a unity json serialization based utility for gltf loading :)

This pull request will enable WMR controller models appearing in compiled windows/uwp applications. Additional work will be required to get these models appearing in the editor.

On github: https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/3595

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with the native models is with their format, Unity does not support "out of the box" gLTF models.  Each SDK that uses them (including steam now) has had to write their own implementation.

The feature is coming very soon (if not merged already) in to the MRTK development branch and will be available for the upcoming RC1 release.  This however, will only feature the model and not the animations (as things change), but this will also be included later.

In the meantime you can place the default Gizmo models with any other model of your choice in the "Input Settings" -> "Controller Visualisation" configuration.

Here's a quick guide to managing controllers - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3e2lwqVPyc

Comment: Thanks so much for this youtube video! Sooooo useful! Where could we find more on other aspects of the MRTK?

Comment: My YT channel is officially launched now and hoping to get more content on ASAP, subscribe to keep updated.  Also, MS are updating their official docs and everyone can help with the docs now.

Comment: Is it still not implemented ?

Comment: This was supposedly resolved in the following PR
https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/pull/3673
But I've not tested it of late.